# Consecutive Numbers in VB 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I want to write code in VB 2008 for consecutive numbers, if they are not consecutive write them in series.

For example : If I have list of integers = 1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 11, 15

I want this kind of language to be passed

1 through 4 , 10, 11, and 15

Please help me !

Thanks

Comment: No its not homework..I need to do at my work.. need to create word document with such language

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you need to loop through them and apply a set of rules for the output depending on the previous value. Also from you example output you will need to test to see if you have reached the end of the array.
Here's a quite verbose way of doing it (vb.net is not a language I typically use so please forgive any mistakes):

```
Public Shared Function TestMethod() As String
        Dim _integers() As Integer = {1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 11, 15}
        Dim _temp As Integer = _integers(0)
        Dim _result As String = _temp.ToString()
        For i As Integer = 1 To _integers.Length - 1
            If (i + 1) = _integers.Length Then
                _result += " and " + _integers(i).ToString()
            ElseIf (_integers(i) - _temp) = 1 Then
                _result += ", " + _integers(i).ToString()
            Else
                _result += " through " + _integers(i).ToString()
            End If
            _temp = _integers(i)
        Next
        Return _result
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution works for the example I listed but if I increase the length of the integer I get wrong output.